# Why is this shape an annulus?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

I have the following shape: $A := $ {$(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \mid \text{Arg}(z) + \text{Arg}(w) = 0 \text{ mod } 2\pi$} inside $\mathbb{C}^2$.

I know that $A \cap S^3 \subseteq S^3 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ is supposed to be an **annulus** (where $S^3$ is the set of pairs $(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2$ such that $|z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1$). (*[here](https://ibb.co/xF1qQXd) for an actual picture of it, embedded in $S^3$)*

It might even be that $A \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ already looks like an annulus by itself, without even having to look at it inside $S^3$, but I'm not sure about that bit. So I'm just mentioning it.

---

The farthest that I can get is that $A =$ {$(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \mid z \underset{\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathbb{R}}{\propto} \bar{w}$} (that is, before intersecting it with $S^3$), but this doesn't help me visualizing it much. And even less, see why it should be an annulus?

Comment: What does it mean for something to "look like an annulus"? That is rather a vague expression, making it hard to know how to answer your question.

Comment: That's a good point. I meant it in a very direct sense, like, this shape \textbf{is} homeomorphic to an annulus. In particular, it will look a bit twisted, like https://ibb.co/xF1qQXd, but it's still an annulus in the usual sense.

Comment: For context, this is from Chenciner's notes on dynamics of the 3 body problem, and this particular construction is the Birkhoff annulus of section. Other methods show that it's homeomorphic to the image of the equator $S^1$ under the geodesic flow of $S^2$; which can be shown to be $D^{*}S^1$, the usual annulus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of *why* this is an annulus is relatively easy to answer on a mathematical level. Perhaps knowing why will aid you in visualizing this annulus, but frankly visualization is kind of a subjective process and I'm not sure I can say much more than answering your question why. Nonetheless I'll say a few words about visualization at the end.

---

To answer the *why*, the first point to make is that for all $(z,w) \in A \cap S^3$, the inequality $|w|^2 + |z|^2 = 1$ implies that $|w| \le 1$ and that $|z| \le 1$. The second point is that, because of the requirement that both $\text{arg}(w)$ and $\text{arg}(z)$ be defined, neither $w=0$ nor $z=0$ is allowed; from this it follows that neither $|w|=1$ nor $|z|=1$ is allowed.

Taking these points altogether it follows that, as $(w,z) \in A \cap S^3$ varies, each of $w$ and $z$ take values in the following open annulus in $\mathbb C$:
$$\mathcal A = \{r e^{i\theta} \mid 0 < r < 1 \}
$$
Define a projection $p : A \cap S^3 \to \mathcal A$, where $p(z,w)=z$. This projection is continuous (obviously). Also $p$ is one-to-one and onto: for each $z = r e^{i\theta} \in \mathcal A$ there exists a unique $w \in \mathcal A$ such that $|z|^2 + |w|^2 = 1$ and $\arg(z) + \arg(w) = 0$, namely
$$w = w(re^{i\theta}) = \sqrt{1-r^2} \, e^{-i\theta}
$$
Finally, this formula shows that $w(z)$ is a continuous function of $z$, and therefore the inverse function $\mathcal A \mapsto A \cap S^2$ defined by $z \mapsto (z,w(z))$ is continuous. This proves that $p : A \cap S^3 \to \mathcal A$ is a homeomorphism.

---

As for visualization, it depends on how you like to visualize the unit sphere $S^3$. One popular method is to use [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Generalizations) which maps $S^3 - \{(1+0i, 0+1i)\}$ diffeomorphically to $\mathbb R^3$. One could certainly use sterographic projection to plot the graph $\{(z,w(z))\}$ of the function $w=w(z)=w(re^{i\theta})$ discussed above, as a subset of $\mathbb R^3$. It seems quite likely to me that this is the intention of the hand-drawn picture that you linked in your post.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very nice answer, and it is exactly what I needed! I admit that maybe I shouldn't have used the "visualization", cause what I wanted was mostly to understand why it was an annulus. So thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: I'd call that image a Mobius strip rather than an annulus.

Comment: That image is definitely homeomorphic to an annulus. Note, for example, that it is oriented (unliked the Möbius strip) and has two boundary components (unlike the one boundary component of the Möbius strip).